# Html5 page onload function does not work without page refresh

Tags: cordova, phonegap

I am new to cordova/phonegap app development. After login page it stores the local storage items and goes to dashboard. From there if I call my profile, for the first time there is no result. But if I refresh the page it calls the api and populates the values successfully. The same thing happens for every page. I am testing with chrome browser.

On the page load, I have used the following code.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/plugins.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/custom.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/semantic.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/angular-route.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            var app = angular.module('postserviceApp', []);
            app.controller('postserviceCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
               $scope.lblMsg = null;

                if (localStorage.getItem("isloggedin")) {
                } else {
                    window.location.assign('login.html');

                }
var custid = window.localStorage["customerid"];
                var token = window.localStorage["token"];
                var data = {"authtoken": token, "customerid": custid};
                $http.post('http://example.com/myprofile/',
                        JSON.stringify(data)).then(function (response) {
                    var loginop = response.data;
                    if (loginop.status === "1") {
                        $scope.custid=loginop.data1.CUSTOMER_ID;
                        $scope.userid=loginop.data1.USER_ID;
                        $scope.firstname=loginop.data1.FIRST_NAME;
                        $scope.lastname=loginop.data1.LAST_NAME;
                        $scope.gender=loginop.data1.GENDER;
                        $scope.dateofbirth=loginop.data1.DOB;
                        $scope.mobile=loginop.data1.MOBILE;
                        $scope.emailid=loginop.data1.EMAIL_ID;
                        $scope.contact=loginop.data1.CONTACT;
                        $scope.status=loginop.data1.STATUS;
                        $scope.pincode=loginop.data1.PINCODE;
                        $scope.state=loginop.data1.STATE;
                        $scope.city=loginop.data1.CITY;
                        $scope.address=loginop.data1.ADDRESS;
                    }
                }, function (response) {
                    $scope.msg = "Error in process";

                });

            });



        </script>
```

I expect on page load it should call the load function automatically every time.

Comment: Use the viewShown event, did you try it?

Comment: Hi Piero Alberto . Do not have any idea on viewShown event. could you share some link or example .

Comment: I can't find any useful links.. can you post all your js code of the page?

Comment: Edited my question with the code. Actually for the when the page loads the tags are blank. If I refresh the page it works as usual by calling the API. Is there any caching technique need to apply.